# AngularJS: Provider after Module.config?

Tags: angularjs

If I want to create a custom provider and configure it within `Module.config`, Angular appears to require the provider be declared first.

This does **not** work:

```js
module.config(function(myServiceProvider) {  });
module.provider('myService', function() {  });
```

This **does** work:

```js
module.provider('myService', function() {  });
module.config(function(myServiceProvider) {  });
```

**Only the order is different.**

I've tried this with `Module.run` as well, and it seems to have the same limitation.  Is there any way around this other than ensuring the config code is loaded after the provider code?

**Edit:** Here's a [JSFiddle of the working order](http://jsfiddle.net/rwtRB/), and a [JSFiddle of the NON-working order](http://jsfiddle.net/rwtRB/1/).  *Note the only thing that changes is the order!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to consider creating separate modules. This will not only allow give you the flexibility you are looking for, it will help to make your code easier to test and maintain.

```
angular.module('myModule', ['myModule.controllers', 'myModule.services']).config(function (myServiceProvider) {
    myServiceProvider.setName('Sam');
});
angular.module('myModule.controllers', []).controller('myController', function ($scope, myService) {
    $scope.name = myService.getName();
});
angular.module('myModule.services', []).provider('myService', function () {
    var name = 'John';
    this.setName = function (newName) {
        name = newName;
    };
    this.$get = function () {
        return {
            getName: function () {
                return name;
            }
        };
    };
});
```

Here is an [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5KQHr/).

Comment: this is very interesting.  I don't know why but I tend to be stingy with my modules.

Comment: Do you have a recommended project folder structure for getting more liberal with modules like this?  I currently organize by type first (service, controller, etc) then by area, but this seems like it would benefit from module first.

Comment: You could take a look at how the `angular-ui/ui-utils` (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-utils) project structures its modules. It allows a consumer to use a single utility or include the entire collection of modules.

Comment: I got `Error: $injector:modulerr
Module Error` following the syntax in your answer with angularjs 1.5.8

Comment: You might want to go back and look at your module names. There is a chance that something was named incorrectly.